# Oracle Case Statement if null select a different table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am selecting some data where we have a set of peoples names, and also a list of preferred names, which may or may not be null. I am checking to see if the preferred first name is null, if it is use the a different table for the name. I understand I need to use a case statement for this, any insight or tips would be appreciated.

Example:

```
SELECT sp1.PREF_FIRST_NAME
CASE  
WHEN sp1.PREF_FIRST_NAME is null 
THEN s1.FIRST_NAME as "Pref_Name"
ELSE  sp1.PREF_FIRST_NAME as "Pref_Name"
END
FROM TABLE1 sp1,TABLE2 s1
```

Comment: How are these tables linked together?  A cross join seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT sp1.PREF_FIRST_NAME, CASE WHEN sp1.PREF_FIRST_NAME is null 
                                 THEN s1.FIRST_NAME
                                 ELSE  sp1.PREF_FIRST_NAME 
                            END as "Pref_Name"
FROM TABLE1 sp1,TABLE2 s1
```

Comment: Wow it was that simple, I was trying to be to difficult about it. Thanks!